# C++/CLI .Net assembly won't load in LabVIEW. Is this due to a fundamental incompatibility with C++/CLI .Net or could there be something going wrong?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, labview

Dependency checker says there are no missing dependencies. It's compiled to .NET 4.0 release x64, and LabVIEW is 64bit as well but LabVIEW says could not load assembly. I have no issue getting a regular C# dll with the same configuration to be loaded from LabVIEW.

Comment: What about _load-time_ dependencies? You can check with MS .net tool [fuslogvw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer)

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Comment: depends.exe also has a profile mode so you could debug-trace LabView's attempt to load native runtime dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Where does your assembly come from?
Did you build it yourself or download from some source?

There are a number of reasons why an homemade assembly wouldn't work, but if it was built by a trustable source/company, this may as well be Windows blocking your assembly: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/delay/p/unblockingdownloadedfile/